# Magento 2.4.2 : Override third party layout file

Tags: layout, extensions, xml, third-party-module, overriding

I have third party module where I want override its layout file.

Third party module file:
**/app/code/Magecomp/Savecartpro/view/frontend/layout/savecartpro_customer_viewcart.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="customer_account"/>
<head>
    <title>Cart Detail</title>
    <css src="Magecomp_Savecartpro::css/savecart.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magecomp\Savecartpro\Block\Customerviewcart" template="Magecomp_Savecartpro::customerview.phtml" name="customerviewcart" cacheable="false" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

The file I created to override is:
**/app/design/frontend/LLW/amp/Magecomp_Savecartpro/view/frontend/layout/savecartpro_customer_viewcart.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="customer_account"/>
<head>
    <title>Cart Details</title>
    <css src="Magecomp_Savecartpro::css/cartlist.css"/>
    <css src="Magecomp_Savecartpro::css/savecart.css"/>
    <css src="Magecomp_Savecartpro::css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css"/>
    <css src="Magecomp_Savecartpro::css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magecomp\Savecartpro\Block\Customerviewcart" template="Magecomp_Savecartpro::customerview.phtml" name="customerviewcart" cacheable="false" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

After overriding, its not taking the changed code.
Where am I wrong with the code.
Help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When adding files within `app/design` you should not include `view/frontend` so the path you should use is `app/design/frontend/LLW/amp/Magecomp_Savecartpro/layout/savecartpro_customer_viewcart.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You put override file-path is wrong please put file on below path.

```
/app/design/frontend/LLW/amp/Magecomp_Savecartpro/layout/savecartpro_customer_viewcart.xml
```

> Note: don't need to create `view/frontend` folder when you override
> file in design theme folder.

Hope this will help you!